# Blog engine supporting multiple blogs in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, blogs

I'm using ASP.NET on my current website and now I need to add some blogs to the site. I need at least 5 multiple blogs and I'm looking for a solution in ASP.NET.

I have been using WordPress before and was looking at [Wordpress MU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WordPress#Multi-blogging) but as I'm running ASP.NET on this website it seems like a bad idea to combine these two. Also the blog is going to be in a subdirectory that I need to protect with ASP.NET so only logged in users can see the blog.

What is the best alternative for multiple blogs in ASP.NET? Or do you think I shall just use WordPress anyway?

Answer (score 1):

Not the best answer:

But it is possible to adjust/extended the open source BlogEngine.net to handle multiple sites.

http://blogengine.codeplex.com/

That being said, it will take some work to make it support a "blog-network", but there are a bunch of developers out there that have done it, and there was an old project based off version 1.3 that handles multiple blogs.

Answer (score 1):

[Blogengine](http://blogengine.codeplex.com/) now has direct support for multiple blogs.

Is very fast and easy to use.
And it can work without a database if you prefer.

To understand how multiple blogs works and how to configure it look at [Introducing Multiple Blogs in Single Instance for BlogEngine.NET](http://allben.net/post/2011/06/19/Introducing-Multiple-Blogs-in-Single-Instance-for-BlogEngineNET.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

There's [Community Server](http://telligent.com/), which is the engine used by MSDN blogs. Back in the day CS used to be an open source ASP.NET showcase project, but it ended up being monetized. I don't know if they still have a free version.